# mongos status is not showing any shard and adding shards also getting failed

Tags: mongodb

Unable to list shards of replica set from Mongos client..

Mongodb Authentication is enabled in sharded cluster.. in config server, the key got changed so cluster stopped working .. I have restored same key and enabled authentication now.. hence after, i am unable to see the shards which were added earlier and also can't able to add same shard again ..

mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("58bd2f7ea00a1d1ce3806bf3")
}
  shards:
  active mongoses:
        "3.2.9" : 1
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:

mongos> sh.addShard("rs01/rs01-p01:27017,rs01-s01:27017,rs01-s02:27017")
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "can't add shard 'rs01/rs01-p01:27017,rs01-s01:27017,rs01-s02:27017' because a local database 'config' exists in another config",
        "code" : 96
}
mongos>

can some one please help me what went wrong and how can configserver can get shards information back..

Comment: Issue resolved.. It is issue with the local config data base created in replica set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same.  I just had to connect to the server I was trying to add, and drop its config database.

```
$ mongo rs01-p01:27017
> use config
> db.dropDatabase()
```

Then on the mongos, I could add the shard as expected.